# Rebus : 8 and your

Tags: rebus

Another easy rebus...  I'll just to make some more creative ones ..

[image]

the image didn't load.  2nd attempt

Comment: @Len I would happily remove them, but the system does not allow me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it by any chance..

> **Urinate** (Your in eight)

Comment: yes :-p, I will try to make a harder one.

Comment: It seemed weird so I got confused :P